# Display error message on second loop of do-while

Tags: c

If I have  a while or do while loop in C, is there some (native) way I can have something happen on the second loop?

I ask for getting inputs; I have this:

```
int size;
do {
        printf("Size of tower (0 <= x <= 23): ");
        scanf("%i", &size);
} while (size > 23 || size < 0);
```

If the user inputs some value which is not between 0 and 23, I want to display an error message and ask for another value. Obviously I could do it like this:

```
int size;
int error = 0;
do {
        if (error) { printf("Invalid size\n"); }
        printf("Size of tower (0 <= x <= 23): ");
        scanf("%i", &size);
        error = 1;
} while (size > 23 || size < 0);
```

However, this feels gross. I'm looking for an elegant solution, and I figure that having something run on the second loop would work.

Comment: Does anybody check the return value from `scanf`?

Comment: BTW `size >= 23` --> `size > 23`

Comment: @EdHeal My checking is in the `while`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do you mean?

Comment: @Quelklef - How are you checking the return value from `scanf` when you are not recording it!

Comment: @Quelklef It does not match the message.

Comment: @Quelklef if `scanf` returns 0 your test of `size` is *undefined behaviour* because `size` is *uninitialised*. Please follow the advice you were given: it is **always** necessary to test the return value of `scanf`, otherwise your work will fall victim to the [GIGO principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: @WeatherVane size is initialized as an int, though? I'm looking into how to fix GIGO right now via some kind of `typeof`.

Comment: @EdHeal Aren't I recording it with scanf? does `scanf("%i", &varname)` not  replace `varname` with the int from the input?

Comment: @Quelklef - Please read the manual page - [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) - It returns an integer. This will indicate if the input is of the right format

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks. This should help.

Comment: `scanf("%i", &size)` can return EOF if it encounters no data, or some hard error on the stream; it can return 1 if there was an integer to be read (and the value of that integer is in `size`); and it can return 0 if there was no integer to read (for example, if you wrote `a` instead of `1`), in which case `size` is not altered, and the `a` is still in the input waiting to be read by the next iteration, which will fail, so you'll generate an error message, and …  You have to check the return value from input functions: `if (scanf("%i", &size) != 1) …process error…`.

Comment: @Quelklef you say "size is initialized as an int, though" but that is untrue. `int size` is defined but *not* initialised because it is a local or automatic variable. Only global or static variables are implicitly initialised to `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
int size = -1;
int MAX_TRIES = 10;
while (MAX_TRIES--)
{
  printf("Size of tower (0 <= x < 23): ");
  if (scanf("%i", &size) != 1)
  {
    printf("Read error!!\n");
    break;
  }

  if (size >= 0 && size < 23)
  {
    break;
  }

  printf("Error: You entered '%d' which is not in the range 0 <= x < 23\n", size);
}
```

By writing it this way, you won't have to compute the negation of your boolean condition logic mentally while writing the code.
Also, checking for the return value of `scanf()` is important. Thanks to  [Weather Vane's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646383/display-error-message-on-second-loop-of-do-while/37646462#comment62773348_37646383) for reminding this.
Further, it is probably better to limit the number of executions of this loop rather than letting it run till infinity. ( Thanks to [Jonathan Leffler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646383/display-error-message-on-second-loop-of-do-while/37646462#comment62775297_37646462) )

Comment: Minor nitpick: you don't declare `scanf_ret`. You could test the return value directly: `if (scanf("%i", &size) != 1) break;`.  Infinite input loops IMO should be avoided. If the result isn't right after many tries, it probably isn't going to be. Use: `enum { MAX_TRIES = 10 }; int tries; for (tries = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++) { …body of your loop… }`. The error message should probably be more helpful than `Error!!` — maybe `printf("You entered %d which is not in the range 0 <= x < 23\n", size);` which lets the user know what the computer thinks they entered and explains why it is invalid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the wonderful advice. I've corrected the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion and error reporting could be moved to a function to simplify the calling code. Input is taken by `fgets` and the value is parsed in the function by `strtol`. This function returns success or failure. Other values get back to the caller through pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int get_int_range ( char *line, char **next, char *delim, int *value, int min, int max);//prototype

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[100] = {'\0'};//input buffer
    int valid = 0;
    int size = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "Size of tower (0 <= x <= 23) or quit\n");
        fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);//read a line
        if ( strcmp ( line, "quit\n") == 0) {
            valid = 0;
            break;// if quit is entered, exit loop
        }
        valid = get_int_range ( line, NULL, "\n", &size, 0, 23);// call to parse a value
    } while ( !valid);// on failure, keep looping the above

    if ( valid) {
        printf ( "Size of tower is %d\n", size);
    }

    return 0;
}

//inputs
// char *line : pointer to text to be parsed
// char **next : pointer to pointer to allow modification of caller's pointer
// char *term : pointer to characters to be considered terminators
// int *value : pointer to int to allow modification of caller's int
// int min : minimum value of range
// int max : maximum value of range
// returns : 0 failure or 1 success
int get_int_range ( char *line, char **next, char *delim, int *value, int min, int max)
{
    long int input = 0;
    char *end = NULL;//will point to end of parsed value

    if ( line == NULL) {
        printf ( "no text to parse\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if ( value == NULL) {
        printf ( "unable to save parsed value\n");
        return 0;
    }
    errno = 0;
    input = strtol ( line, &end, 10);//get the integer from the line. end will point to the end of the parsed value
    if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( input == LONG_MAX || input == LONG_MIN))
    || ( errno != 0 && input == 0)){// parsing error from strtol
        perror ( "input");
        return 0;
    }
    if ( end == line) {// nothing was parsed. no digits
        line[strcspn ( line, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
        printf ( "input [%s] MUST be a number\n", line);
        return 0;// return failure
    }
    // *end is the character that end points to
    if ( *end != '\0' && !( delim && strchr ( delim, *end))) {// is *end '\0'? is *end in the set of term characters?
        line[strcspn ( line, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
        printf ( "problem with input terminator: [%s] \n", line);
        return 0;
    }
    if ( input < min || input > max) {// parsed value is outside of range
        printf ( "input out of range %d to %d\n", min, max);
        return 0;
    }

    if ( next != NULL) {// if next is NULL, caller did not want pointer to end of parsed value
        *next = end;// *next allows modification to caller's pointer
    }
    *value = input;// *value allows modification to callers int
    return 1;// success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred technique would involve duplicating the input, but would simplify your loop:

```
printf("Size of tower (0 <= x <= 23): ");      // Try to get good input once.
scanf("%i", &size);

while (size < 0 || 23 < size ) {               // While the user is wrong:
    printf("Invalid size\n");           
    printf("Size of tower (0 <= x <= 23): ");  // Try, try again.
    scanf("%i", &size);
}
```

Comment: Why not check the return value from `scanf` - If not 1 then swallow the bad input. Your code will enter into an infinite loop

Comment: This is WET code, though. I know this could be done, but I want to avoid this.